# merge user35633 with DamienC

Tags: support

would it be possible to merge this account (user35633) with my former account from before the migration (DamienC... which I can't access anymore) ?

Thanks in advance

Best

Damien

Answer (score 3):

Just just the form at https://meta.mathoverflow.net/contact and select "I need to merge my user profiles" to contact SE for the profile merge. They'll probably see this meta post at some point, but the form will be quicker and they'll get the necessary information to perform the merge

Comment: Thanks. I did so. But they are asking for users profile of the type meta.mathoverflow.net/... while my old account is not of this type.

Comment: @user35633 The user ids should be identical as the users were all imported into the new site. So your old user should be on the new site with the old user id.

Comment: The problem is that http://mathoverflow.net/users/7031/damienc exists while http://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/7031/damienc does not. And for some reason the form only accepts an url of the type http://meta.mathoveflow...

Comment: @user35633 Just submit the form with the information you have, SE should be able to sort it out somehow

Comment: "contact SE for the profile merge": I did this two times in the last month and nothing happend.